# Exporting Firebase Crashlytics Data to BigQuery Partially

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, crashlytics

Is it possible to filter the data to be exported to BigQuery? For example I just want to have fatal crashes [(is_fatal=TRUE)](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9036484?hl=en) to be exported but not non fatal exceptions which allocates much more space in my case.

I checked out data transfer options but could not find anything related to filtering or schema customization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only configuration options for the exporting Crashlytics data to BigQuery are to:

1. Turn it on or off
2. Enable streaming of intra-day events (if your project is on the Blaze plan)

It's not possible to control what crash data is exported beyond that.

If you want less data to be stored in BigQuery, you'll have to copy the data you want to keep over to new tables, and delete the ones generated by the integration.